# Confused about the value of a number and the range of the number in C

Tags: c, binary, unsigned, bit, unsigned-integer

I missed my lecture and I don't understand the last two points. Can someone explain the third point and show me how to calculate the forth point? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The value of a number is the sum of the values of the bit positions
>   containing 1.

If converting a number from binary to decimal, you have to keep on multiplying the bit value with 2^(position value - 1) //[ assuming position value starts from 1 on the rightmost side] and summing the value with the previous values obtained in this way.

So, if the bit is 0, then the result has to be 0, irrespective of the bit-position. Hence, it doesn't add any value to the number. Only the bits having 1 count to the value.

> What range of numbers can be represented in an unsigned integer type
>   with :  4 bits, 8 bits, 16 bits, 32 bits, n bits?

For an unsigned integer of `n bits`, the integers represented can be from 0 to (2^n)-1.

```
So, 4 bits can represent numbers from 0 to (2^4) - 1 = 15.
8 bits can represent numbers from 0 to (2^8) - 1 = 255.
16 bits can represent numbers from 0 to (2^16) - 1 = 65,535.
32 bits can represent numbers from 0 to (2^32) - 1 = 4,294,967,295.
```

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Point 3: referring to the table above, the binary value `00010001` represents the decimal `16 + 1 = 17`.

Point 4: an unsigned binary number of `n` bits can represent the range `0` to `2**n - 1`, meaning (2 to the power n) - 1.

Again referring to the table, a 4-digit binary number with all bits set represents `8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 15`, which is also `2**4 - 1`.